# Set both the name and location for writeline?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, streamwriter

I want to set both the name and the location for a writeline procedure. I am allowing the user to select the path using a dialog box but can't seem to set both the name and location w/o getting an error. I am using VS 2010.

```
        strFileLocation = dlgFolderBrowser.SelectedPath

    Dim swrExportFile As New StreamWriter(strFileLocation)
```

Thanks in advance, Josh

Comment: If that answer isn't what you meant, could you expand a bit more on your problem?

Comment: That is what I mean but it's not writing at all when I add the location.

Comment: I used @JonoRR 's solution but added a '\' before the filename.

Like so:

    Dim swrExportFile as New StreamWriter("C:\My\File\Location\" + "\myFileName.txt")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you mean, but by name and location; do you mean filename and the directory the file will be in?

If so, you can pass it in as one to the StreamWriter:

```
Dim swrExportFile as New StreamWriter("C:\My\File\Location\" + "myFileName.txt")
```

Comment: It's not writing it at all if use that. Are you sure I need to use a '+' symbol?

Comment: Okay I got it, just gotta add a '\' before the filename. Thanks!

Comment: I broke up the string for demonstration, the '+' just combines those two strings together ie, that just turns into - "C:\My\File\Location\myFileName.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a saveFileDialog might be more appropriate for this task